# how to check allocated buffer's corresponding page is in cache or main memory?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

At application level i use malloc() and memset() and in driver i use get_user_pages_fast() to pin the corresponding pages.

Is there a way in linux to determine whether to check these pages are in cache or in main memory ?

Comment: If they are in the cache they are also in main memory. XY problem? Not clear what you want

Comment: IIRC, in some architectures, you can lock cache lines. In many architectures, you can prefetch things to cache. But in general, cache is sort-of-by-definition meant to be hidden layer between processor and memory, and in most architectures it's entirely hardware controlled and invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a device-specific call that allows you to pin them to the cache, the CPU is free to move them in and out of the cache as it sees fit.  Even if you can check if the address is question is in the cache, the information is not reliable when you execute the next statement in your driver.